# How to get flat files with no file structure as source and insert same data into table as target in IICS

Tags: informatica, iics, iics-di

I wanted to get the flat files as source without any file structure specified using IICS(Informatica Intelligent cloud services). Flat files names can be anything, and structure also will change any. And also need to create table dynamically based on flat file and insert into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of options here. You can use a fully parameterized mapping niside a taskflow that will start on file listener, prepare the parameters and statements to be executed as part of the pre-SQL statement on your Target.

Inside the mapping you define Source and Target as parameterized - and that's briefly it!

Comment: Have tried as per your suggestions. Now my source and target is fully parameterized. Same calling from TF, and also am using FL for input file name and assigning same to input as Data task in TF. But TF is getting suspended while running, unable to see input parameter values of Data task and output of FL. Can you please share any other ways solve this issue.

Comment: Please download and review the session log

Comment: Now am trying to pass input parameters to Mapping task through Task flow. But in My Task flow File listener is picking multiple files at a time(more than 1) but when i passing to Mapping  task, its passing only one file name as input parameter. Do we have any ways to call multiple input parameters to Mapping task so that all files will move to target location. Please suggest.

Comment: The File Listener will capture all files - this is by design. At any given time there may be many new files. File Listener returns an array. You need to create a loop. Create Assignment Task and get one file to a variable. Create Decision Task to check if array is not empty. Invoke mapping and pass the current file name as parameter. Jump to Assignment Task.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Also if you free time, can you see my another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522058/how-to-drop-and-create-new-table-everytime-using-mapping-iics

Comment: In this case consider upvoting and marking as correct - thanks!